# Wordpress dequeue scripts without handle?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using Foobox lightbox (free) plugin, and apparently the plugins' files are loaded on every page regardless of whether it's used or not. However I would like to change this, but I can't seem to find any handles to dequeue the scripts through.

It seems that the scripts are called by the code beneath, which to me at least, doesn't show any handles. I've tried using `remove_action(...)` to "counter" them as well as various inputs in `wp_dequeue_script()` to try and target the files directly - e.g. `wp_dequeue_script('foobox.free.min.js')`

```
class Foobox_Free extends Foo_Plugin_Base_v2_1 {

        const JS                   = 'foobox.free.min.js';
        const CSS                  = 'foobox.free.min.css';
        const CSS_NOIE7            = 'foobox.noie7.min.css';
        const FOOBOX_URL           = 'http://fooplugins.com/plugins/foobox/?utm_source=fooboxfreeplugin&utm_medium=fooboxfreeprolink&utm_campaign=foobox_free_pro_tab';
        const BECOME_AFFILIATE_URL = 'http://fooplugins.com/affiliate-program/';

        private static $instance;

        public static function get_instance() {
            if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) && ! ( self::$instance instanceof Foobox_Free ) ) {
                self::$instance = new Foobox_Free();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the plugin by setting localization, filters, and administration functions.
         */
        private function __construct() {
            //init FooPluginBase
            $this->init( FOOBOXFREE_FILE, FOOBOXFREE_SLUG, FOOBOX_BASE_VERSION, 'FooBox FREE' );

            if (is_admin()) {

                add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'admin_inline_content'));
                add_action('foobox-free-settings_custom_type_render', array($this, 'custom_admin_settings_render'));
                new FooBox_Free_Settings();

                add_action( FOOBOX_ACTION_ADMIN_MENU_RENDER_GETTING_STARTED, array( $this, 'render_page_getting_started' ) );
                add_action( FOOBOX_ACTION_ADMIN_MENU_RENDER_SETTINGS, array( $this, 'render_page_settings' ) );

                add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'admin_notice_foogallery_lightboxes' ) );
                add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobox_foogallery_lightboxes_ignore_notice', array( $this, 'admin_notice_foogallery_lightboxes_ignore' ) );
                add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobox_foogallery_lightboxes_update', array( $this, 'admin_notice_foogallery_lightboxes_update' ) );
                add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_notice_foogallery_lightboxes_inline_js' ), 999 );

                add_filter( 'foobox-free-has_settings_page', '__return_false' );

            } else {

                // Render JS to the front-end pages
                add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontend_print_scripts'), 20);
                add_action('foobox-free_inline_scripts', array($this, 'inline_dynamic_js'));

                // Render CSS to the front-end pages
                add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontend_print_styles'));

                if ( $this->is_option_checked('disable_others') ) {
                    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'disable_other_lightboxes'), 200);
                }
            }
        }
```

How, if possible, do I dequeue these scripts (and styles) without editing the plugin file directly?

**Edit**
Below I've added the things I've tried doing to remove the scripts (all added to functions.php):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_foobox_scripts', 100 );

function remove_foobox_scripts() {
   if ( !is_page('my-page') ) {

       wp_deregister_script( 'foobox.free.min.js' );
       wp_dequeue_script( 'foobox.free.min.js' );
     }
}
```

Also tried the below, which is just a straight copy from the foobox file:

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontend_print_scripts'), 20);
remove_action('foobox-free_inline_scripts', array($this, 'inline_dynamic_js'));

remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontend_print_styles'));
```

Also tried the below, where the `array(` part is removed:

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','frontend_print_scripts', 20);
remove_action('foobox-free_inline_scripts', 'inline_dynamic_js');

remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frontend_print_styles');
```

Comment: Where have you inserted your code to try and counter them? What code are you using to specify which pages they should / shouldn't load on?

Comment: @miknik sorry for the slow response. I've added the attempts which I've tried without success to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the way you are trying to do this stems from the order in which things happen in Wordpress.

You are relying on the conditional tags like `is_page('my-page')` to determine whether or not to load the plugin. These conditional tags do not become available until Wordpress has parsed the URL for the current query, and at this point all the plugins and your theme have already been loaded. Even if you parse the URL yourself instead of using the conditional tags you cannot be sure your code will run before the plugins are loaded.

The solution is to add your code as an [mu-plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). These are loaded before normal plugins so you can use an [option (option name)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/option_(option_name)) filter here to alter the plugins you want to be loaded.

Option filters pass an array to your function containing the values which are set for that option, so in this case you want to hook `option_active_plugins`.

You can find the values to use for by running `print_r(get_option('active_plugins'));` or look through the plugins folder of your wordpress install.

The following example is specific to your question, but you could modify it to make a more comprehensive set of rules, adding and removing multiple plugins on different pages based on many conditions.

My function checks you are not in `wp-admin` and then has 2 conditions. The first disables a normally active plugin on the specified pages, the second enables a normally disabled plugin on the specified pages.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'add_or_remove_plugins' );
function add_or_remove_plugins( $plugins ) {
    if (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/' ) !== 0) {  // Disable in admin pages or admin plugin settings stop working properly
        if (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/remove-plugin-here/' ) === 0) {  // Conditonal tags still unavailable so you have to parse urls yourself
            $k = array_search( 'foobox-image-lightbox/foobox-free.php', $plugins );    // This will stop an active plugin from loading
            if( false !== $k ){
                unset( $plugins[$k] );
            }
        }
        if (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/add-plugin-here/' ) === 0) {
            $plugins[] = 'foobox-image-lightbox/foobox-free.php';  // This will load the plugin along with all the active plugins
        }
    }
    return $plugins;
}
?>
```

To install just change the values to suit, paste into a file and upload into your mu-plugins folder

**EDIT**

Looks like your inline js is added to `wp_head` during the constructor of the `Foobox_Free` class. You could try adding this to your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_dynamic_js' );
function remove_dynamic_js(){
    $foo = Foobox_Free::getInstance();
    remove_action('wp_head', array($foo, 'inline_dynamic_js'));
}
```

or if that doesn't work then maybe this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_dynamic_js' );
function remove_dynamic_js(){
    remove_action('wp_head', array('Foobox_Free', 'inline_dynamic_js'));
}
```

The action is added inside a private function, so I don't know if either of those will actually work. Give it a shot. If not my first answer will as it stops the plugin from loading at all on the specified pages.

**UPDATE**

Well, I was close... Here's the code to remove the scripts, as supplied by the plugin author.

```
$foobox = Foobox_Free::get_instance();
remove_action('foobox-free_inline_scripts', array($foobox, 'inline_dynamic_js'));
```

Comment: I was actually just about to write an update myself as I've succesfully managed to deregister the scritps loaded by the plugin with the following: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_foobox_scripts', 100 );
function remove_foobox_scripts() {
   if ( !is_page('my-page')) {

       wp_dequeue_script( 'foobox-free-min' );
       wp_dequeue_style( 'foobox-free-min' );
       wp_dequeue_style( 'foogallery-core' );
     }
}`. However this does not remove the inline script `inline_dynamic_js`.

Comment: Scripts come later so you can disable those with conditionals, I thought you were trying to stop the whole plugin from loading.

Comment: Ah I see, that might not have been obvious. Do you have any idea as to how to disable the inline script? I've tried a multitude of different stuff, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Edited my answer with some suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately they doesn't seem to work in this instance. The first suggestion throws this error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Foobox_Free::getInstance()` while the second seemingly doesn't apply/remove anything. I guess it's because it's defined in a private function as you mentioned. Completely stopping the plugin might be the best/only solution afterall. Thanks

Comment: you were on the right path! I've got an answer from the plugin developer and the following removes the inline script: `$foobox = Foobox_Free::get_instance();
remove_action('foobox-free_inline_scripts', array($foobox, 'inline_dynamic_js'));` from here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-inline-scripts-on-pages-where-its-not-needed/#post-9723042 . Maybe you could add this to the answer for future reference? :)

Comment: Good idea, I've added it to my answer

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use ```strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/' )``` and not ```is_admin()``` to check if you're in the backend or not?

Comment: @gillespieza I alreay covered the reason in my answer, it's because of the order in which Wordpress loads - `conditional tags do not become available until Wordpress has parsed the URL for the current query, and at this point all the plugins and your theme have already been loaded`